# NestJs CQRS - aggregate setup with co existing TypeORM entities

Tags: typescript, nestjs, cqrs

So there is an official example here

https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/nest-cqrs-example

and I tried to create my own for three simple features:

- Fetching all users
- Fetching one user by id
- Creating a user

I'm using TypeORM and have a basic User entity. So based on the official sample code I created a command handler for creating users ( `create.user.handler.ts` ):

```typescript
@CommandHandler(CreateUserCommand)
export class CreateUserHandler implements ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand> {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersRepository: UsersRepository,
    private readonly eventPublisher: EventPublisher,
  ) {}

  public async execute(command: CreateUserCommand): Promise<void> {
    const createdUser: User = await this.usersRepository.createUser(
      command.username,
      command.password,
    );

    // const userAggregate: UserAggregate = this.eventPublisher.mergeObjectContext(
    //   createdUser,
    // );
    // userAggregate.doSomething(createdUser);
    // userAggregate.commit();
  }
}
```

All it does is persisting a new user entity to the database. But what I didn't get for now is what to do with the User aggregate. When merging the object context I can't pass in the created user entity. And further I don't know which logic should be handled by the aggregate. So based on this user aggregate ( `user.model.ts` ):

```typescript
export class User extends AggregateRoot {
  constructor(private readonly id: string) {
    super();
  }

  public doSomething(user: UserEntity): void {
    // do something here?

    this.apply(new UserCreatedEvent(user));
  }
}
```

I know that I can raise the event, that a new user was created and push it to the history. But is it the only thing it's responsible for?

So how would I setup the user aggregate and create user handler correctly?

When passing in the created entity I get an error like

> Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AggregateRoot'. Type 'User' is missing the following properties from
> type 'AggregateRoot': autoCommit, publish, commit, uncommit, and 7
> more.ts(2345)

which makes sense because the TypeORM entity extends `BaseEntity` and the aggregate extends `AggregateRoot`. Unforunately the official example doesn't show how to deal with aggregates AND database entities.

**Update**: Deleted link to temp repository, as it no longer exists.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @cojack assumes that your TypeORM entity definition and CQRS AggregateRoot are defined by one and the same class. Many NestJS + CQRS projects are implemented like that (Though it is not best-practice and violates the single-responsibility principle. And your domain classes should not have dependencies on your database).

As you state in the comments this is problematic if your TypeORM definition must extend from `BaseEntity`, as you cannot also extend from `AggregateRoot`.

But there is no requirement to do so. In your command handler you can make calls to the `UsersRepository` to e.g. validate if a user with that name already exists, and then to create the user.

Then in your `mergeObjectContext` you can instantiate the aggregate root entity defined in a separate class and pass appropriate information from the User entity you just created.

An example of this can be found in the [nestjs-rest-cqrs-example](https://github.com/kyhsa93/nestjs-rest-cqrs-example/blob/master/src/account/application/command/handlers/account.handler.command.create.ts) project:

```typescript
@CommandHandler(CreateAccountCommand)
export class CreateAccountCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<CreateAccountCommand> {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(AccountEntity) private readonly repository: AccountRepository,
    private readonly publisher: EventPublisher,
  ) {}

  async execute(command: CreateAccountCommand): Promise<void> {
    // Validation of the command (check if account with this email already exists).
    await this.repository.findOne({ where: [{ email: command.email }]}).then((item) => {
      if (item) throw new HttpException('Conflict', HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    });

    const { name, email, password } = command;
    // Create the account via the repository. The TypeORM entity is returned.
    const result = await this.repository.save(new CreateAccountMapper(name, email, bcrypt.hashSync(password)));

    const account: Account = this.publisher.mergeObjectContext(
      // Create the AggregateRoot entity to be passed to the context.
      new Account(result.id, name, email, result.password, result.active),
    );
    account.commit();
  }
}
```

This project does not do much in terms of events in the aggregate root, but you get the idea, I hope.

There are many ways to lay out the CQRS model and places to add your logic. For a more complex, but well laid-out example see e.g. [Daruma Backend](https://github.com/AdrianLopezGue/daruma-backend/blob/master/src/user/application/handler/create-user.handler.ts) by Adrian Lopez.

Answer (score 4):

This `doSomething` function which you mention, it's exactly for what you have described, to emit an event. I doesn't see any additional features for it, because we moved all of the business logic from "models" to "services", so yeah.

Reply to comment,because comments have disabilities

Instead of:

```js
    const createdUser: User = await this.usersRepository.createUser(
      command.username,
      command.password,
    );

    const userAggregate: UserAggregate = this.eventPublisher.mergeObjectContext(
      createdUser,
    );
    userAggregate.raiseUserCreatedEvent(createdUser);
```

Do

```js
    const userAggregate: UserAggregate = this.eventPublisher.mergeObjectContext(
      await this.usersRepository.createUser(
        command.username,
        command.password,
      )
    );
    userAggregate.raiseUserCreatedEvent();
```

then in `user.model` do:

```js
public raiseUserCreatedEvent(): void {
    this.apply(new UserCreatedEvent(this));
  }
```

btw, if you will get rid of type `: User` in line:

```js
const createdUser: User = await this.usersRepository.createUser(
```

it might work, because you explisity set a type here, which is not necessary, typescript can guess type by his own, so you don't have to do it by your own, in this kind of situation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what do I have to pass into the mergeObjectContext function? Because I can't pass in the user TypeORM entity

Comment: @Question3r exactly this is what Im passing as param to the `mergeObjectContext` function, why you can't pass TypeORM entity?

Comment: so when I do this https://github.com/matthiashermsen/temp-cqrs/blob/master/src/users/commands/handlers/create.user.handler.ts#L21 I get the error `Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AggregateRoot'.
  Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'AggregateRoot': autoCommit, publish, commit, uncommit, and 7 more.ts(2345)`

Comment: and my second question would be if the aggregate looks fine and should only do this ... raise events ... https://github.com/matthiashermsen/temp-cqrs/blob/master/src/users/models/user.model.ts#L11

Comment: @Question3r I have update anwer, because comments here have disability

Comment: thanks for your reply. I updated my code. So for the command handler I have https://github.com/matthiashermsen/temp-cqrs/blob/master/src/users/commands/handlers/create.user.handler.ts#L17 and for the aggregate I have https://github.com/matthiashermsen/temp-cqrs/blob/master/src/users/models/user.model.ts#L11 but unfortunately I still get the error `Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AggregateRoot'.
  Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'AggregateRoot': autoCommit, publish, commit, uncommit, and 7 more.ts(2345)`

Comment: and btw. if I should pass in the repository call directly as a parameter, why it's not possible to pass in the result as a parameter =? My personal opinion would be to do the call before and pass in the variable for better readability :)

Comment: Ahh I see what you have done, you mix your user model with user entity, that's the case. So merge it to the one class and it will works like a charm.

Comment: sorry what do you mean with that? what should I do with the entity and what with the aggregate =?

Comment: Combine it together as one class, because what your repository method `createUser` is returning is a `User` instance but it's from TypeORM BaseEntity, but `mergeObjectContext` expect to have `AggregateRoot` instance. So you have 2 models one file is `user.entity.ts` and second one is `models/user.model.ts` it will not work like that, so you have to merge these two classes together into one class.

Comment: hmm but how should I do that because the user entity is extending the BaseEntity and the user aggregate is extending the AggregateRoot ...

Comment: both seem to be abstract classes and no interfaces :/

Comment: hmm unfortunately the offical sample is not showing how to do that https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/nest-cqrs-example

Answer (score 0):

`mergeObjectContext` method should receive AggregateRoot instance as an argument

```
const userAggregate = this.eventPublisher.mergeObjectContext(new User(createdUser.id);
```